# Subsetting in R using a list

Tags: r, subset

I have a large amount of data which I would like to subset based on the values in one of the columns (dive site in this case). The data looks like this:

```
 site   weather depth_ft depth_m vis_ft vis_m coral_safety coral_deep rate
alice      rain       95      NA     50    NA            2          4    9
alice      over       NA      25     NA    25            2          4    9
steps     clear       NA      27     NA    25            2          4    9
steps                 NA      30     NA    20            1          4    9
andrea1   clear       60      NA     60    NA            2          4    5
```

I would like to create a subset of the data which contains only data for one dive site at a time (e.g. one subset for alice, one for steps, one for andrea1 etc...).

I understand that I could subset each individually using

```
alice <- subset(reefdata, site=="alice")
```

But as I have over 100 different sites to subset by would like to avoid having to individually specify each subset. I think that subset is probably not flexible enough for me to ask it to subset by a list of names (or at least not to my current knowledge of R, which is growing, but still in infancy), is there another command which I should be looking into?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

This will create a list that contains the subset data frames in separate list elements.

```
splitdat <- split(reefdata, reefdata$site)
```

Then if you want to access the "alice" data you can reference it like

```
splitdat[["alice"]]
```

Comment: I also find this helpful https://twitter.com/hadleywickham/status/643381054758363136

Answer (score 1):

I would use the plyr package.

```
library(plyr)
ll <- dlply(df,.variables = c("site"))
```

Result:

```
>ll
$alice
   site weather depth_ft depth_m vis_ft vis_m coral_safety coral_deep rate
1 alice    rain       95      NA     50    NA            2          4    9
2 alice    over       NA      25     NA    25            2          4    9

$andrea1
 site weather depth_ft depth_m vis_ft vis_m coral_safety coral_deep rate
1 andrea1   clear       60      NA     60    NA            2          4    5

$steps
   site weather depth_ft depth_m vis_ft vis_m coral_safety coral_deep rate
1 steps   clear       NA      27     NA    25            2          4    9
2 steps    <NA>       30      NA     20     1            4          9   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

`split()` and `dlply()` are perfect one shot solutions.

If you want a "step by step" procedure with a loop (which is frowned upon by many R users, but I find it helpful in order to understand what's going on), try this:

```
# create vector with site names, assuming reefdata$site is a factor
sites <- as.character( unique( reefdata$site ) )

# create empty list to take dive data per site
dives <- list( NULL ) 

# collect data per site into the list
for( i in 1:length( sites ) )
{
 # subset
    dive <- reefdata[ reefdata$site == sites[ i ] , ]
 # add resulting data.frame to the list
    dives[[ i ]] <- dive
 # name the list element
    names( dives )[ i ] <- sites[ i ]
}
```